# Как работать с такими объектами javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть объект для хранения многоуровневого списка

```
var x = {
    "Toyota": {
        "Corolla": {
            "Поколение 1990-97": null,
            "Поколение 1999-2002": null,
            "Поколение 2001 -2004": null
        },
        "Rav 4": null,
        "Land Cruiser": null,
        "Avensis": null
    },
    "Volkswagen": null,
    "Ford": null
}
```

Как отобразить ключи первого уровня - Toyota, Volkswagen, Ford?
 Как отобразить ключи второго второго, например - Corolla, Rav 4, Land Cruiser, Avensis?
 Как добавить-удалить ключи в "ветке" этого объекта?

Answer (score 4):

> Как отобразить ключи первого уровня - Toyota, Volkswagen, Ford?

Есть отличная функция [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
var x = {
  "Toyota": {
    "Corolla": {
      "Поколение 1990-97": null,
      "Поколение 1999-2002": null,
      "Поколение 2001 -2004": null
    },
    "Rav 4": null,
    "Land Cruiser": null,
    "Avensis": null
  },
  "Volkswagen": null,
  "Ford": null
}

console.info(Object.keys(x));
```

> Как отобразить ключи второго второго, например - Corolla, Rav 4, Land Cruiser, Avensis ?

Так же как и первый уровень, только передайте в `Object.keys` ссылку на нужный уровень:

```js
var x = {
  "Toyota": {
    "Corolla": {
      "Поколение 1990-97": null,
      "Поколение 1999-2002": null,
      "Поколение 2001 -2004": null
    },
    "Rav 4": null,
    "Land Cruiser": null,
    "Avensis": null
  },
  "Volkswagen": null,
  "Ford": null
}

console.info(Object.keys(x.Toyota));
```

> Как добавить-удалить ключи в "ветки" этого объекта?

Добавление происходит установкой свойства (то, что через точку с присвоением).
Удалить свойство/метод может оператор [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```js
let x = {};

// Добавление:
x.some = 'thing';
console.info(x.some); // thing

// Удаление:
delete x.some;
console.info(x.some); // undefined
```

---

Советую Вам изучить основы работы с объектами, например, [тут](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/intro).